# momentjs is not returning same output for same timezone in different input format

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I'm having issue while using the moment js library.

```
let moment = require("moment-timezone")

date = '02/15/2018 5:00 PM'
fmt = 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A'
timezone = 'America/New_York'

moment.tz(date, fmt, timezone) //Statement 1
```

Output> moment.parseZone("2018-02-15T17:00:00.000-05:00")

```
moment().tz(timezone) //Statement 2
```

Output> moment.parseZone("2018-06-26T04:33:51.173-04:00")

Both statements are using same timezone but hour difference is different from UTC.
First one is showing 5 hours difference and second one is showing 4 hour difference.

If I use the following format then it shows the correct datetime.

```
moment.tz({year:2018, month:2, day:15, hour:17}, timezone) //statement3
```

Output> moment.parseZone("2018-03-15T17:00:00.000-04:00")

I'm not able to understand why statement 1 is not giving the correct datetime.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: New York is UTC-5 during winter and UTC-4 in summer. See [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Comment: But why statement 1 & statement 3 is giving UTC-5 & UTC-4 respectively when they are parsing the same datetime.

Comment: The first is parsing, the third is using a constructor where the months are zero-indexed. Note the final output: 15th February in 1 and 15th March in 3.

Comment: The difference is because the first date is in February, outside daylight saving time while the second date is in June, which is inside daylight saving time. So the UTC offset is -5 and -4 respectively.

Comment: Thanks @Phylogenesis

Comment: @TerryLennox - Please post as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is because the first date is in February, outside daylight saving time while the second date is in June, which is inside daylight saving time. So the UTC offset is -5 and -4 hours respectively for each date.

Remember, the UTC offset for most timezones will vary by the time of year, *never* assume a fixed offset in your code.